# User Managment using MapProxy (WMS)

Tags: authentication, mapproxy

My goal: I'd like to publish a secured WMS on ArcGIS Server and then use MapProxy for limiting the access to it. For each user, the same WMS layers shall be available, but a different geographical extent (i.e. each user shall see the data of a different municipality / province).

What I know: By using the [MapProxy Authorization API](https://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/auth.html#limited-to) (limited_to), a geographical extent can be set.

What kind of user management do I have to implement for the authorization by user?